# How to skip part of php when webpage reloads on form input submit?

Tags: php, html

I have below a short program. When I press the submit button, the button is supposed to turn green. This works as intended. However, when I press the submit button, the whole page reloads and gives an alert that I only intends it to do when the page initially loads and not every time when I press the submit button. Every time I press the submit button, the only thing that I intends is to have the button turn green. Is there a way to prevent the first line of php from executing when I press the submit button? Much appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">     
        <style type="text/css">
            .sub
            {
                background-color: #1f5a7c;
                border: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form method="POST" >       
            <input type="submit" name="TestButton" id="TestButton" value="Test Button" class="sub">
        </form>                                                 
    </body>
</html>

<?php   
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>";

    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"]))         
    {                                   
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>TestButton.style.background='green';</script>";    
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That `php` will run every time .. You can use an `else` to prevent this.. IE

```
<?php   

if(isset($_POST["TestButton"]))         
{                                   
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>TestButton.style.background='green';</script>";    
}else{
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!  Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['TestButton'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>";
}
<?php>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP conditional statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) to skip the part of code.
You can wrap states of the form in if...else statement.

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"])) {                                   
?>
<form method="POST" >
     <!-- Here you can change it as you want to -->
  <input type="submit" name="TestButton" id="TestButton" value="Test Button" class="sub green someother_class">
</form>

<?php
    else {
?>
<form method="POST" >       
  <input type="submit" name="TestButton" id="TestButton" value="Test Button" class="sub">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Or you can make it short by adding a variable and changing it's value accordingly-

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"])) {                                   
      $classes = "sub green some_other_class";
    else {
      $classes = "sub";
    }
?>

<form method="POST" >
     <!-- Here you can change it as you want to -->
  <input type="submit" name="TestButton" id="TestButton" value="Test Button" class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
</form>
```